# We have migrated from Mariadb 10.1.21 to mysql 5.6 using phpmyadmin 5.0. After migrating we are facing issues in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mariadb

The stored procedure was working fine in Mariadb. After migrating to mysql it is not returning any rows nor any errors. Kindly help to resolve this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJtKp.png)

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `ONROLL`(IN `SCH_ID` INT, IN `YR_ID` INT)
    MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN
DECLARE GRD_ID INT;
DECLARE FINISHED INT;
DECLARE GRD_CUR CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINCT GRADE_ID FROM SECTION WHERE SCHOOL_ID = SCH_ID ORDER BY GRADE_ID ASC;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET FINISHED = 0;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ROLL(
GRD_ID INT,
COUNT INT);

OPEN GRD_CUR;
LOOPROWS:LOOP

FETCH GRD_CUR INTO GRD_ID;

IF FINISHED = 0 THEN
    LEAVE LOOPROWS;
END IF;

INSERT INTO ROLL (GRD_ID,COUNT)
SELECT GRD_ID,COUNT(U.ID) FROM USER U JOIN USER_CURRICULUM UC ON UC.USER_ID=U.ID JOIN COHORTS_STUDENTS CS ON CS.STUDENTS_ID=UC.USER_ID AND CS.ACADEMIC_YEAR=UC.YEAR_ID JOIN COHORTS C ON C.ID = CS.COHORTS_ID WHERE UC.SCHOOL_ID=SCH_ID AND UC.GRADE_ID=GRD_ID AND UC.YEAR_ID=YR_ID;

END LOOP;
    CLOSE GRD_CUR;
    SELECT * FROM ROLL;
    DROP TABLE ROLL;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. It seems your question is a little light on details.  Do you have sample data? Have you tried debugging individual pieces of your stored procedure to see if all the pieces still work?

Comment: Please add the create statement.

Comment: Hi, Yes i have tried each and every query separately and it works fine. I have created in phpmyadmin through add routine window. so i have posted only the definition part above. @jnovack

Comment: This seems to be a debugging/data issue and you need to help us help you by providing debugging details (edited into you question). Your question implies: *you actually get a result (grd_id, count), but it is empty*, is that correct? In that case, the only way to achieve that seems to be if the `section`-table does not have `SCHOOL_ID`-rows that match your `SCH_ID`-parameter. Please verify that. Try to extend akinas fiddle by some sample data to match your (empty) result and/or describe where it does not match the behaviour in your system.

Answer (score 0):

Your procedure code does not assign an initial value to `FINISHED`, you just declare it as `INT`, and set it to zero in your `NOT FOUND` handler.

So it is not really determined what value `FINISHED` has to begin with, and depending on whether it is initialized as zero or a non-zero value by default your `FETCH LOOP` may terminate early without storing anything in your `ROLL` table.

By changing the FINISHED declaration to

`DECLARE FINISHED INT DEFAULT 1;`

your could should become deterministic and return the same result on both MariaDB and MySQL.

Comment: Actually, declarations in MySQL are deterministicly initialized with `null` if they don't have a default value. Looks strange, and should be fixed just because of that, but doesn't seem to be the issue here.